# I want to print a random array in a function (It is also ok if it is not in function) in C#. How can I do?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, random

static void array()
{

```
            //1dimensional
            string[] a = new string[4];
            string[] one_one = { "X" };
            string[] one_two = { "X", "X" };
            string[] one_three = { "X", "X", "X" };
            ////2dimensional
            string[,] one_four = { { "X", "X" }, { "X", "X" } };
            string[,] two_two = { { "X" }, { "X" } };
            string[,] two_three = { { "X" }, { "X" }, { "X" } };
            
            
        }
```

In there i want to print random array with using random command.
Im new at using functions so I don't have much idea
If it is possible to solve it without  "functions" too, I will be glad if you help, thanks

Comment: Explain how you plan to use the "random array".  Are we mixing the one-dimensional and two-dimensional arrays in our choice.  Give us an example of some "output" you might expect...

Comment: You mean you want to select one one of the arrays shown in your code at random, and print its contents? Or you mean you want to generate an array whose contents are random? It's unclear. It's also unclear where you're stuck. Do you know how to generate a random number in C# (if not, it's quite easy to google it)?

Comment: Sorry Im new here. Yes I want to mix one-dimensional and 2-dimensional arrays and my example output is like XX

Comment: That doesn't answer the questions I asked.

Comment: Yes I know how to generate random numbers ,and  I want to select one one of the arrays shown in  code at random, and print its contents

Comment: Okay, so generating the output for the one-dimensional arrays is trivial with `String.Join()`, but there is no built-in method for outputting the two-dimensional arrays.  You'd have to write a loop and generate a string, presumably a multi-line string to represent the different "rows" in the those 2D arrays?    Will it ONLY be 1D or 2D?

Comment: It would make sense to put these arrays into another array (or list) so that you can then choose an index of that array at random (using a random number generator), which then gives you the array that you will output.

Answer (score 1):

If we only deal with the one-dimensional arrays, then you could make an array of arrays to choose from, then use `String.Join()` to make your output string:

```
Random R = new Random();
string[][] arrays = {a, one_one, one_two, one_three };
var arr = arrays[R.Next(arrays.Length)];
String output = String.Join("", arr);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

You could do a similar thing with just the two-dimensional arrays, but you'd need a loop to put the "rows" together into one string.

Mixing the 1D and 2D into one selection makes it trickier.  It's possible (see below), but I do **NOT** recommend doing it this way as this is a horrible design:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // One-dimensional
    string[] a = new string[4];
    string[] one_one = { "X" };
    string[] one_two = { "X", "X" };
    string[] one_three = { "X", "X", "X" };

    // Two-dimensional
    string[,] one_four = { { "X", "X" }, { "X", "X" } };
    string[,] two_two = { { "X" }, { "X" } };
    string[,] two_three = { { "X" }, { "X" }, { "X" } };

    Random R = new Random();
    Object[] arrays = {a, one_one, one_two, one_three, one_four, two_two, two_three };
    var arr = arrays[R.Next(arrays.Length)];

    string output = "";
    switch (((Array)arr).Rank) {
        case 1:
            output = String.Join("", (String[])arr);
            break;

        case 2:
            string[,] arr2D = (string[,])arr;
            for(int r=0; r<=arr2D.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c<=arr2D.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
                {
                    output = output + arr2D[r, c];
                }
                if (r<arr2D.GetUpperBound(0))
                {
                    output = output + Environment.NewLine;
                }       
            }
            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to mix 1d and 2d either but I have to do a tetris style project and I can't think of anything else thank you. @Idle_Mind